# Are there such things as private NodeJS applications?

Tags: node.js

I am currently learning NodeJS and was curious to know if you can make private NodeJS applications. What I mean by private is that the application (which uses nodeJS as its server side technology) is not available on the web by searching up a url, instead the application sits only on certain computers.

For example the company I was previously doing an internship for made an iOS application for a bank that gets installed on all the bank's employee's phones. The app was not available on the App store, but instead was only available on the mobile devices of the bank's employees.

Are there such applications for nodeJS, and if so are there any popular ones you are aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Availability of an application isn't correlated to the technology you use to build it. It depends on the technology you use to deploy it.

For example, you can build a NodeJS application and use it to [build a robot](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs/wiki/Projects-using-RobotJS) or perform some [machine learning](https://github.com/erelsgl/limdu) on your local machine or setup a private web server on your local network or make a web server publicly available on the internet.

Only the 4th one would be available via a public URL because you decided to deploy it as such.

You could replace NodeJS above with many other technologies and the purpose wouldn't change.

Comment: Thanks alot. I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

A private internet is called an intranet. Most companies have their own intranet.

You can even run a webserver just on your computer, that is called `localhost` or more technically the loopback network interface. Given you are learning Node you are probably already using the localhost of your own machine for development and teaching examples.

Here is some reading material

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intranet
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: Thanks. I looked into intranet and it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where the application is deployed ;)